# Setting a cookie won't work javascript

Tags: javascript, cookies

I'm using the Javascript below to set a cookie but it doesn't set a
cookie. Chrome's debugger gives me no errors and all the variables are
correct. It just doesn't seem to set the cookie. `document.cookie`
remains as "". Can anyone suggest why the cookie is not getting set?

```
function setCookie(name,value,exdays){
    var date=new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime()+(exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires="expires="+date.toGMTString();
    document.cookie=name + "=" + value + "; " + expires + "path=/";
} // setCookie ends
```

If you need to know, I tried using the call `setCookie("username","user",365);`.

EDIT: added the missing "=", the code still doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are runnig this code/file locally, then chrome does not set the cookie, If you will put it on remote server then it(page) will work.

For testing purpose you can run this page from **xampp/htdocs.**

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `=` between name and value. Also, You need a semi-colon after expires

```
 document.cookie= name + "=" + value + "; " + expires + ";path=/";
```

Comment: can't believe i missed that but i changed it and it still behaves just the same as before.

Comment: @user3211924, Try `document.cookie= name + "=" + value + "; " + expires + ";path=/";` You need semi-colon after expire

Answer (score 0):

What I have found, is if you set the cookie a few times too quickly, then Chrome will stop the cookie from being updated at all.  I have not tested this on any browser besides chrome.  But the only way I have found to fix this is to completely quit Chrome and start it back up.  After this the cookie for that page will be blank.

I am assuming this is some sort of security with Chrome, to make sure a third party/virus/bad advertisement doesn't interfere with your website's cookies.  I couldn't find and documentation of this at all though, this is just a guess as to what is happening.